# query formula: select all where column in sheet a= column in sheet b

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, formula

I have 2 sheets in one spreadsheet(assume sheet A and sheet B)

and I want to query all data from sheet B(SELECT *) to sheet A

WHERE value of column E in sheet A = value of column E in sheet B

AND value of column G in sheet A = value of column F in sheet B

what should the formula be?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter formula to achieve that `=filter('Sheet A'!A2:Z,'Sheet A'!E2:E = A1)`

Enter the formula in cell `A2` of Sheet B, and enter your filter term in cell `A1`

Comment: I don't know why but this take only 4 last column of sheet A

Comment: Incorrect range entered in the formula? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet so I can see what the problem is?

Comment: you can see on this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wb0c-eqinhLFgpxuJXKcjdbrnRYaHgqLcsjQerYvl-Q/edit#gid=0     Sheet1 is sheetA and summary is sheet B ,I put this filter on H2 
 filter(Sheet1!A2:Z,Sheet1!E2:E = A2:A) because there're value in many rows to filter not just one cell.

Comment: Actually I want to join 'summary' sheet to 'Sheet1' sheet which is the same value on column 'countryname' and 'policyname'